# Multiple issues with Apple Bluetooth keyboard: no auto connect, battery always 0%

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I'm running 14.04 on a pc, and I can get my A1314 keyboard to work, but the only way is to hold down the power button until it starts seeking, then disonnect and reconnect it in bluetooth settings.

I have a Microsoft Bluetooth mouse and it works properly. I get to the GDM and after a few seconds it connects automatically. Not so with the keyboard, though.

Additionally, it always shows in the battery indicator as having 0% power. So I never know how much power it actually has left.

Also, I can't manually disconnect it. Once connected it always stays on.

Answer (score 0):

The A1314 keyboard takes a minute to connect in Ubuntu. You don't actually have to touch the power button. You just press any key, and after several seconds the bluetooth will connect and the keyboard will start working.

I think I was getting impatient and hitting the power button, which would just disconnect and reconnect the bluetooth.

My solution was to install blueman, and add it to the startup programs. Then, when I boot, I can see that the keyboard isn't connected. I can press a key, and I can see if bluetooth detected the keyboard. I can then see when I have a signal, an after a few more seconds, the keyboard will start working.